# Inside a Metal shader code, how to define an in/out parameter variable of a function?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, metal, metalkit

I have this function:

```
void myFunct(const int A, ?out? int B){B = B + A;}
```

How to declare `B` in such a way that the function can update its value and return it to the caller?

Comment: Assuming standard C++ sematics in Metal, `void myFunct(const int A, int &B) { B = B + A; }`

Answer (score 0):

Metal is a C++ based programming language that allows you to pass a pointer to a function. To do so, simply declare the function parameter as a pointer type.

```
void myFunct(const int A, device int *B)
{
   *B = *B + A;
} 

device int *C = 0;
myFunct(1, C);
```

You can also pass variable by reference:

```
void myFunct(const int A, device int &B)
{
   B = B + A;
} 

device int *C = 0;
myFunct(1, *C)
```

or pointer by reference:

```
void myFunct(const int A, device int *&B)
{
   *B = *B + A;
} 

device int *C = 0;
myFunct(1, C);
```

Comment: thanks 0xBFE1A8, however what the difference between using &B like @bg2b suggest and using *B ?

Comment: & indicates a reference.  It's basically a pointer under the hood, but you don't have to write *B.  Also, you're guaranteed that the reference points to something (it can't be a null pointer).  Either method will work though.

Comment: @loki in c++, we can pass parameters to a function either by pointers or by reference. In both the cases, we get the same result. [What are the reasons we use one over the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in)